# How to update value of nested json object using volley post methd?

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

I am working on a project, in which user will enter his data and we need to store the data using API. I have to update values in nested json object.

I am using POST method in volley to update data. My problem is that i am not able to update the nested JSON object.

I am also using GSON so i have model class for the Result, Address & contact.

before updating

```
{
    "id": 58,
    "address": null,
    "contact": null
}
```

after updating

```
  {
    "id": 58,
    "address": {
        "id":50,
        "first_line": "first_line",
        "locality": null,
        "state": "state",
        "country": "country"
    },
    "contact": {
       "primary_number": "primary",
       "secondary_number": "secondary"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: post what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following the way

```
try {
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

            obj.put("id", 58);

            JSONObject contact=new JSONObject();
            contact.put("id", "smome value");
            contact.put("first_line", "smome value");
            contact.put("locality", "smome value");

            JSONObject address=new JSONObject();
            address.put("primary_number", "primary");
            address.put("secondary_number", "secondary");

            obj.put("address", address);
            obj.put("contact", contact);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now the output will look like as below

```
   {
  "id": 58,
  "address": {
    "primary_number": "primary",
    "secondary_number": "secondary"
  },
  "contact": {
    "first_line": "smome value",
    "locality": "smome value",
    "id": "smome value"
  }
}
```